# Putting HTML content inside of a PHP template

Tags: php, html

I'm fairly new to web development, and I'm making a website using PHP server side for my templating etc. My basic page design has a header (contained in top_menu.php), as well as several `<link>` or `<script>` tags in the head that I would like to be in every page.

Here's a skeleton of what I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/common/js/overall.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include '../../common/php/top_menu.php'; ?>
        <!--I want to add content here in the body-->
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, there's no way to `include` this skeleton on each page because I want to put the HTML content **inside** of the template, where I've indicated with the comment. I could split the template into a 'top' and a 'bottom' half so I include the top, write the content, then include the bottom, but that would be a lot harder to maintain.

What is the standard practise for something like this? Surely people need to do this all the time?

Comment: Often people will rely on a PHP framework like [Symfony](http://symfony.com/) or [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/). However, using frameworks comes with much more learning and complexity. For what you are trying to accomplish, creating a 'top' and 'bottom' template and including them on each page is probably your best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate files for header ans footer like.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/common/js/overall.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include '../../common/php/top_menu.php'; ?>
```

And save this file as header.php and create another file for footer as footer.php.

```
</body>
</html>
```

include header.php at the top of each page and footer.php at the bottom of each page.

Comment: Yeah I suggested doing that, but surely there's a better way?

Comment: If you are using any Framework or any template engine like Smatry then they have their own mechanism to handle this, but if you are developing your system in core php then this is best and easiest way.

Comment: Incidentally could you give me an example or link me to an example of doing this with Smarty? It would seem simpler than splitting my templates.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to create a blog script, You would have to create 3 files to have your expected output:

First, create a `header.tmpl.php` file:

```
<!-- start of header.tmpl.php -->
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="/common/js/overall.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
             <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <!-- more links here -->
             </ul>
        </div>

<!-- end of header.tmpl.php -->
```

Now create a `footer.tmpl.php` file:

```
<!-- start of footer.tmpl.php -->
        <footer>
            <p>Copyright @ yourname.com</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- end of footer.tmpl.php -->
```

Then you can create a `blog.php` file:

```
// import header file
<?php require 'header.tmpl.php'?>

// your blog script

// import footer file
<?php require 'footer.tmpl.php'?>
```